# Typeorm doesn't return generated data id

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

Im using Typeorm (v8.0.2) and Nestjs(v8) with Nodejs(v16).
My problem is when I create a book Typeorm doesn't return generated book id

Here is **Book.entity**

```
@Entity()
export class Book {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
id: number;

@Column()
title: string;

@Column()
author: string;
}
```

And this is **book.service**

```
async createBook(createBookDto: CreateBookDto): Promise<Book> {
  const book = await this.bookRepository.create(createBookDto)
  await this.bookRepository.save(createBookDto)
  return book
}
```

and when I use postman and create a Book it just returns

```
{
   title: "example"
   author: "foo"
}
```

id of generated book is missing

Comment: According to documentation, `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` is already in auto-increment by default. I don't see anything in doc showing that you can use `'increment'` as an argument for `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`.

Comment: A couple of enhancements can be done. 1) `await` has no purpose with `this.bookRepository.create(createBookDto)` 2) You should use `await this.bookRepository.save(book)` instead of `await this.bookRepository.save(createBookDto)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: return result of `this.bookRepository.save(createBookDto)`, not `this.bookRepository.create(createBookDto)`

From the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api):

`create` - Creates a new instance of `User`. Optionally accepts an object literal with user properties which will be written into newly created user object.

```
const user = repository.create(); // same as const user = new User();
const user = repository.create({
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Timber",
    lastName: "Saw"
}); // same as const user = new User(); user.firstName = "Timber"; user.lastName = "Saw";
```

In your example you are using `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()` decorator that uses database level auto-increment function. The value of this column will be generated after the `save()` method, not after `create()`.

Answer (score 1):

What happened in my case was that a developer defined `id` in the entity file with a `@PrimaryColumn` decorator rather than a `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator, and nest was not returning the `id` after `save()`.

It must be `@PrimaryGeneratedColumn`.  e.g.,

`@PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name:'id', type:'bigint' }) id !: number`